# How to count feature exists amount within a SparseVector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+---+-------+--------------+
| id|clicked|     features |
+---+-------+--------------+
|  7|  1.0  |(4,[3],[1.0]) |
|  8|  0.0  |(4,[2],[12.0])|
|  9|  0.0  |(4,[3],[0.1]) |
+---+-------+--------------+
```

and have converted it to a RDD:

```
Row(id=7, clicked=1.0, features=SparseVector(4, {3: 1.0}))
Row(id=8, clicked=0.0, features=SparseVector(4, {2: 12.0}))
Row(id=9, clicked=0.0, features=SparseVector(4, {3: 0.1}))
```

Now I want to find the number of exists for each feature. For example, in my dataframe/rdd, features column contains 5 features (0 to 4). Since feature in index 0, 1, and 4 do not contain any values, their amounts are 0. And feature index 2 is 1, feature index 3 is 2.

I want get that information within a dictionary data structure. How to do it?

```
{0:0, 1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:0}
```

I'm using PySpark, but an answer using Scala is also fine.

Comment: Your `SparseVectors` contain 4 features, not 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to do the counting before the `SparseVector` was created. If that is not an possible, you essentially have two options (until `VectorUDT`s are [easily castable into arrays](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19217)).

In both cases, the way to count the number of values that exist per feature is the same. Loop over the range of the size of the `SparseVector` and check if that index exists in the `SparseVector.indices` list. This will return counts for all features, including those where the count is 0.

A simpler way could be to create tuples of the form `(index, 1)` for each index in `SparseVector.indices`, but this would exclude from the final output any features without any values.

#### Option 1: Define a `udf`, `explode`, and aggregate:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

featureCount_udf = f.udf(
    lambda r: [(x, int(x in r.indices)) for x in range(r.size)],
    ArrayType(
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("featureNumber", IntegerType()),
                StructField("count", IntegerType())
            ]
        )
    )
)

df.select(f.explode(featureCount_udf("features")).alias("features"))\
    .select("features.*")\
    .groupBy("featureNumber")\
    .agg(f.sum("count").alias("count"))\
    .show()
#+-------------+-----+
#|featureNumber|count|
#+-------------+-----+
#|            0|    0|
#|            2|    1|
#|            1|    0|
#|            3|    2|
#+-------------+-----+
```

#### Option 2: Convert to `rdd` and `flatMap`:

```python
from operator import add

df.select("features")\
    .rdd\
    .flatMap(
        lambda r: [(x, int(x in r["features"].indices)) for x in range(r["features"].size)]
    )\
    .reduceByKey(add)\
    .toDF(["featureNumber", "count"])\
    .show()
#+-------------+-----+
#|featureNumber|count|
#+-------------+-----+
#|            0|    0|
#|            2|    1|
#|            1|    0|
#|            3|    2|
#+-------------+-----+
```

Here we `flatMap` each `row` to tuples of the form `(featureNumber, containsValue)`. Then we can call `reduceByKey` to add the indicator variable for each feature.

---

#### Original Answer

If you want the output in a dictionary, you're going to have to call `collect()` at some point.

```python
data = df.select("features").collect()
```

Now that you have the data as list of `pyspark.sql.Row`s, you can iterate through and use `.indices` and `.size` to identify which columns have values.

```python
print([[int(x in r["features"].indices) for x in range(r["features"].size)] for r in data])
#[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

From this you can create a `numpy` array and sum the columns. Finally call `enumerate` on the result and pass that to the `dict` constructor.

Putting it all together:

```python
mydict = dict(
    enumerate(
        np.array(
            [[int(x in r["features"].indices) for x in range(r["features"].size)]
             for r in data]
        ).sum(0)
    )
)
print(mydict)
#{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2}
```

Comment: Since my dataset is in TB level, I cannot use collect() in my code. Is there a way to avoid it? Not in a dictionary is fine.

Comment: @Ippon are you starting from the SparseVectors? Is there any way to operate on your original data, before converting to features?

Comment: Since the data contains features in million level, it comes within a SparseVector.